# What's the difference between the two list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I just solved a question in LeetCode, however I found that the two different list comprehensions produce different results. So what's the difference?

```
ans = [[0] * (n-2)] * (n-2)
```

```
ans = [[0] * (n-2) for _ in range(n-2)]
```

The question is LeetCode 2373, and the two different results are as follows:
This solution gives the wrong answer because of the list comprehension

```
class Solution:
    def largestLocal(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        n = len(grid)
        ans = [[0] * (n-2)] * (n-2)
        print(ans)
        
        for i in range(n-2):
            for j in range(n-2):
                ans[i][j] = max(grid[x][y] for x in range(i, i+3) for y in range(j, j+3))
        return ans
```

Comment: The first example is not a list comprehension. Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly?

Comment: Try `print([id(v) for v in ans])` for both cases. In the first, you'll notice that python expanded the outer list list with multiple references to a single inner list in the first example but created new lists in the second example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[expression] * n` evaluates `expression` once, so you'll get a list with *n* occurrences of the same value (and as Iain Shelvington pointed out, this is *not* a list comprehension). `[expression for element in source]` reevaluates `expression` for every `element` in the `source` (and this *is* a list comprehension).

In your situation, this means that the first version will produce a list where each element is the *same* list of zeroes, so if you set an element in one of the inner lists, you'll actually set it in all the inner lists.

Comment: oh thanks, I should have noticed that.

Comment: @DogFish: It's a common Python trapdoor (and a badly designed aspect of the language, IMO, since it's usually not what you want). Even something as simple as `[[]] * n` in an attempt to get _n_ empty lists suffers from the same effect, where all the empty inner lists are the same. However, you've also discovered the proper solution, which is to use a list comprehension, which in this simpler example would be `[[] for _ in range(n)]`.